# Batch scripting - add special character to output for Codeception command

Tags: batch-file, codeception

I am writing a bat file to automate the process of the below Codeception command.

```
php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/SigninCest.php:^anonymousLogin$
```

The problem is that I cannot output the `^` character for example:

```
set functionNamePrefix=^^
set output=php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/SigninCest.php:
set functionName=anonymousLogin
set functionNamePostFix=$
set command=%output%%functionNamePrefix%%functionName%%functionNamePostFix%
```

the `$` symbol is correctly displayed but the `^` is not.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the variable in quotes:

```
set "functionNamePrefix=^^"
```

Now the variable `%functionNamePrefix%` will contain `^`.

Answer (score 1):

Special characters such as the `%|^` are seen as operators to `cmd`.

When you `set functionNamePrefix=^^` and try to echo it, you effectively allow `cmd` to utilize the special character. Therefore, `echo %functionNamePrefix%` will give the `more` prompt, as `cmd` is expecting the next input line because of the `^`.

When however you double quote a string, you are excluding the character in the current `cmd` run. It is however also recommended to double quote strings when using `set` to ensure you eliminate unwanted whitespace. For instance:

`set var=value`

Note the accidental space after value, this space will form part of the value as long as it exists, so enclose everything in double quotes to play safe and to ensure the special characters are not becoming functions in the current batch run.

```
set "functionNamePrefix=^^"
set "output=php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/acceptance/SigninCest.php:"
set "functionName=anonymousLogin"
set "functionNamePostFix=$"
set "command=%output%%functionNamePrefix%%functionName%%functionNamePostFix%"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining my answer by posting this helpful answer, upvoted